# hive can't change column type Invalid column reference

Tags: hive

My table

```
CREATE TABLE `db.t`(
  `ctn` string,
  `balance` string)
PARTITIONED BY (
  `time_key` date)
```

I try to change time_key to string

```
ALTER TABLE db.t CHANGE time_key time_key string;
```

But get

```
Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask. Invalid column reference time_key
```

Why?

Comment: Partitions columns are actually not real columns and they are saved differently in the metastore, so it seems they were not taken in account when the CHANGE feature was developed.

Comment: @Dudu The link helped. This `alter table db.t partition column (time_key string);` works.

Comment: I know, I tested it first :-) (P.s. I upvoted @sokhaty answer and you might want to do the same)